# Manipulation the zoom property in CSS3

Tags: html, css, reactjs, meta-tags

I want my React app will be seen as the same as when a user changes the zoom level to  90%.
I tried that issue with CSS

`body {
       transform: scale(0.9);
 }`

but in this way, the screen is not similar to zoom level changes. I tried applying my desire size by meta tag, but it wasn't successful.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the css zoom property to set your default zoom value. Here's the css demo code.

```
#my{
zoom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why does firefox not support this?

Comment: it's supported by firefox as well. Take a look at their documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: I did look there. Look below the heading *Browser compatibility*. It seems firefox doesn't support it.

Comment: try the mozilla specific css property -moz-transform: scale(value); to zoom your html elment